# iPhone: How to get array of values through web service?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, ipad, nsxmlparser

I am consuming web Service in iPhone and parsing it through `NSXMLParser`. My service returns Array of objects but when I get it from web service it and concatenate same  type of values. Web service generates the below response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetClientTripsResponse xmlns="http://tempori.net/">
      <GetClientTripsResult>
        <TripNumbers>
          <ConfirmationsNumber>string</ConfirmationsNumber>
          <TripState>string</TripState>
        </TripNumbers>
        <TripNumbers>
          <ConfirmationsNumber>string</ConfirmationsNumber>
          <TripState>string</TripState>
        </TripNumbers>
      </GetClientTripsResult>
    </GetClientTripsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For ConfirmationsNumber is 6 Digit number and TripState is string value NONE or ONWAY

But when I parse it gives

ConfirmationsNumber = 234589455623784523 and

TripState = NONENONEONWAY

means it parse three objects and concatenate them. I want there isolated values or at-least comma separated. like 234589,455623,784523 or what ever but should be split able.

Below is code

```
@interface TrackTripStatus : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *tripList;
    UILabel *noTripsLabel;
    int indexCount;
    BOOL elementFound;

    // for Web service
    NSMutableData *webData;
    NSMutableString *soapResults;
    NSURLConnection *conn;
    NSXMLParser * xmlParser;
    NSString * qelementName;
    NSString * RequestStep;
}

- (void) getClientTrips;
-(void) setControls;
@end

- (void) getClientTrips
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *CLIENTPHONENUMBER = [defaults stringForKey:@"CLIENTPHONENUMBER"];
    if(CLIENTPHONENUMBER == nil)
        CLIENTPHONENUMBER = @"";

    NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                         "<soap:Body>"
                         "<GetClientTrips xmlns=\"http://tempori.net/\">"
                         "<HomePhone>%@</HomePhone>"
                         "</GetClientTrips>"
                         "</soap:Body>"
                         "</soap:Envelope>",CLIENTPHONENUMBER]; 

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: WebServiceURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];
    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req addValue:@"http://Itcurves.net/GetClientTrips" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; //---set the HTTP method and body--- 
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
    [req setHTTPBody:[soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"%@\n", soapMsg); 
    RequestStep = @"GetClientTripsResult";
    if (conn) {
        [conn release];
    }

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    if (conn) 
    { 
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
}


-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {

    [webData setLength: 0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data 
{ 
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error {
    NSLog(@"Test: %@", error);
    [webData release]; 
    [connection release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
{ 
    NSLog(@".........DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]); 
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc]    //---shows the XML---
                        initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length]
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"\n\n %@",theXML);
    if([theXML length] < 120)
    {
        if(indexCount < 3)
        {
            if([RequestStep isEqualToString:@"GetClientTripsResult"])
                [self SendClientInfo];
            indexCount = indexCount +1;
        }
        else {
            RequestStep = @"end";
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result" message:@"Server was unable to process request" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show]; 
            [alert release];
        }

    }   

    [theXML release];                                                                                       


    /*  CODE TO RELEASE XML start  */
    if (xmlParser) 
    { 
        [xmlParser release];
    }
    [soapResults setString:@""]; 

    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData]; 
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self]; 
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES]; 

    /*  CODE TO RELEASE XML end  */
    NSLog(@"Step: %@, %@",RequestStep, soapResults);
    if([RequestStep isEqualToString:@"GetClientTripsResult"])
    {
        qelementName = @"ConfirmationsNumber";
        [xmlParser parse];
        if ([soapResults length]> 0) 
        {
            NSString * ConformNo = soapResults;
            qelementName = @"TripState";
            [soapResults setString:@""];
            [xmlParser parse];
            if ([soapResults length] > 1) {
                NSLog(@"Step2: %@, %@",RequestStep, soapResults);
                indexCount =0;
                RequestStep = @"end";



            }
            else{               
                qelementName = @"DeclineReason";
                [soapResults setString:@""];
                [xmlParser parse];
                RequestStep = @"end";               
            }
        }
    }   
    if([RequestStep isEqualToString: @"end"])
    {
        //  [connection release];                                                                                                                                    
        //  [webData release];      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I use the NSXMLParser I use the callbacks to parse it. Here is the code I use for this:

First set the delegate and a class variable

```
@interface FooBarClass : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    NSMutableString *currentElementValue;
}
```

then wherever you need to get the url and set the xmlparser

```
NSString *address = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://somewebservice"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:address];

NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

[url release];

[xmlParser setDelegate:self];

[xmlParser parse];
[xmlParser release];
```

and then the callbacks:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Foo"]) {  //start of main element to save
    if (Bar) 
    {
        [Bar release];
        Bar = nil;
    }
    Bar = [BarType alloc];
}

//finding characters in an element. could be multiple calls so append here
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{

if(!currentElementValue)
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
else
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}

//ending elements
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{

NSString *trimmedValue = [currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Foo"])   //this is the end of the top level object so add it to our array
{
    [fooArray addObject:Bar];

}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Foo2"])  //this is one of the features so we set it in our object
{
    Bar.fooBarString = trimmedValue;
}



[currentElementValue release];  //release this to make room for the next element
currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i worked with library called sudzc, and it generate all the methods of the web service, so you don't have to parse the server response and get directly arrays ready to use.